# Undefined index error if any element is empty

Tags: arrays, object, laravel-5, undefined

I am sending 5 input values on single click in angularjs. Data is send as objects of object. For example

`Object{0:Object, 1:object, 2:Object .., 5:Object}`.

Every object have Two inputs say first name and last name. User can send any input pair.

I am sending this as post request. Now on Backend side, I m using Laravel. I m storing this object in a variable let say 
 `$x=$request->input('data');

I loop it for every object it will create new record.

Problem I am facing:
If all objects is sends then it properly saving the data in database.
But if one of the object is empty, Empty means if use enter 2nd input and 3rd input only and leave blank the 1st, 3rd and 5th input.

Then laravel throwing error of undefined index as on first object it not receiving any firstname or lastname for 1st request. SO how can I solve this problem.I wanted that it should update the fields whichever it receives.

Comment: @Mohammad: please show the request json you send when you fail to save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the input values in ajax function and pass those key values only

Comment: There is no other way to handle this in laravel??

Comment: you must print the posted data you will get the array format which hence you will get why looping gives undefined index error;

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to filter out empty objects before persisting.

```
$data = $request->input('data');
$dataToSave = [];
foreach ($data as $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $dataToSave[] = $data;
    }
}
// persist $dataToSave with your logic
```

Its better to change your `firstname` and `lastname` to `nullable` in order to accept `null` values

Comment: @humbledust way works our for me.Thanks in anticipation.